# How to transfer a file from local machine to remote server with desired permissions using putty

Tags: files, putty

I am trying to transfer a large file to a remote server using putty.During transferring the file (since the file is large it takes some time to transfer ) the permissions for are set to some default read only (rw-r----).

I need to set the permission for the file while the file transfer is in process  ( that means when the file is being transferred). How can I do this in putty? Please anyone suggest something.

I am new to linux commands could you please provide some syntax that i can follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979727/7359328) is what you're looking for.

Pasting it here so I can add some explaining to it:

> You could use `rsync` for the transfer:
>
> ```
> rsync --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx file.txt user@host:abc/
> ```

This moves file `file.txt` to directory `abc` inside `user`'s home at `host` while also setting the specified permissions. If you need to set an absolute path and not one that's inside the home dir of `user`, just write said full path, leading slash included (e.g.: `user@host:/abs/path/`).

> If you prefer to use `scp`, you could set permissions after the transfer:
>
> ```
> scp file.txt user@host:abc/
> ssh user@host 'chmod 755 abc/file.txt'
> ```

This is the same as the previous step, but divided into two commands; first the upload, then the permissions change. You asked for it to be handled with just one command, the same that makes the upload, but I think having an extra choice might help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

The actual PuTTY application is a terminal emulator, it does not transfer files as such. But it comes with `psftp` and `pscp` file transfer commands.

Unfortunately, neither `psftp` nor `pscp` will allow setting the file permissions *while* the file is being transferred. The option `-p` for `pscp` will preserve the file timestamps, but not the permissions. With `psftp`, the file transfer commands `put` and `mput` don't have an option to specify the remote permissions, but there is a separate `chmod` command you can use to set the file permissions after the transfer is complete. [See chapter 6.2.14 of PuTTY documentation for information on the `chmod` command of `psftp`.](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-commands)

If you have something that will automatically process the file immediately after you have transferred it, note that you might want to first transfer the file using `psftp` either:

- to a different directory
- or to a temporary filename that does **not** match what the automation is looking for

and after the transfer is complete, set the permissions with `chmod`, and finally use the `mv` command to either move the file to the directory that is used by the automation, or to rename the file to its actual, expected name.

(On any POSIX-compliant unix-style filesystem, any operation to move/rename a file within a single filesystem must be an *atomic operation*, i.e. other processes will see the file operation either as "not done yet" or "completely finished", never "in progress" in any way. Here this property is used to ensure that the automation will not see the file it expects until it is completely transferred and has permissions set to allow access.)

This procedure will also help to guarantee that the automation will never catch a file that is still in the process of being transferred, or is left incomplete because a network connection failed in mid-transfer.

For example, you could make a script like this: (e.g. `filetransfer.scr`)

```
cd /some/directory
mkdir incomplete_xfer
cd incomplete_xfer
put file.txt
chmod a+rw file.txt 
mv file.txt ..
cd ..
rmdir incomplete_xfer
```

and then run it with:

```
psftp remoteuser@remotehost -b filetransfer.scr
```

Or if you know that the remote end expects `*.xml` files and won't react to files with any other suffix, you could do it like this too: (alternative `filetransfer.scr`)

```
cd /some/directory
put file.xml file_tmp_incomplete_xfer
chmod a+rw file_tmp_incomplete_xfer
mv file_tmp_incomplete_xfer file.xml
```

Comment: I can set the permissions for the file after the transfer is complete manually, not a problem. But i want to simulate a scenario (for a test case) where we have large file being imported that can be used by oracle procedure. The behaviour that is being tested is that the oracle procedure needs to wait until the complete file is being transferred and then start processing it. If the file while it is being transferred has wrong permission the oracle procedure throws an error (cannot open file ) without testing the real behaviour. How can i transfer the file with the required permissions.

Comment: With the `pscp` and `psftp` tools, **you cannot specify the permissions together with the transfer**. So you must **either** do something to make sure the oracle procedure will not see the file where it expects it until you have set the permissions as a separate operation, **or** use some other tool, e.g. `rsync` as suggested in [Santiago Botto's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670401/258991).